# Yielding well-formed-ness warning when XML seems to be OK

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-manifest, markup

I got this error out of the blue, my XML seems to be fine and I don't know if I'm missing something. Is my XML well-formed, and if not, why?

This is the error I get:

```
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.jwanhsulaiman.talktagthree" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AsyncTaskActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I checked validation sites which claim to check for well-formed-ness as opposed to just validation, but no luck, they seem to accept my XML.

Comment: I checked your XML. It is well-formed.

Comment: I was kinda hoping it's not because now I don't know where the issue is!

Comment: I tried to track the error and it seems to ought to be on line number 6 column number 6? @YitzhakKhabinsky

Comment: It is possible that there are invisible characters in the XML. You can try to check it in Notepad++. To do that go to menu View = > Show Symbol => Show All Characters

Comment: Very smart but unfortunately not it. I'm starting to think it got to do with Android Studio but I don't know where to go from here

Comment: If I got this error I would be double and triple checking that the XML I've given to the parser is the XML that I'm staring in the face.

Comment: The error about content appearing after the root element is only going to be detected after reading the `</manifest>` end tag. So if it's saying line 6, that's a strong indication that it's actually parsing a different document from this one.

Comment: @MichaelKay You mean the XML may be parsed differently in Android Studio than as shown? How could I see what's parsed? The code above is exactly what I'm using though, I checked!